# v8 create object without methods

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

I'm work on next version of [v8-profiler](https://github.com/node-inspector/v8-profiler) and now I want to simplify it.

I see that my class (`ProfileNode`) don't needs hidden link to internal object (`v8::CpuProfileNode`), because my class don't uses internal object methods.

- Can I delete getter methods and replace it like the example below?
- Is it wrong realisation?
- Is it hight memory usage?
- Or it's OK?

(I'm novice in c++ and v8 library)

(Please ignore version uncompatibility - it's not a part of question)

This is a part of current [`profile_node.cc`](https://github.com/node-inspector/v8-profiler/blob/master/profile_node.cc)

```
Persistent<ObjectTemplate> ProfileNode::node_template_;

void ProfileNode::Initialize() {
  Local<ObjectTemplate> tpl = NanNewLocal<ObjectTemplate>(ObjectTemplate::New());
  NanAssignPersistent(ObjectTemplate, node_template_, tpl);
  tpl->SetInternalFieldCount(1);
  tpl->SetAccessor(String::New("functionName"), ProfileNode::GetFunctionName);
  ...
}

NAN_GETTER(ProfileNode::GetFunctionName) {
  NanScope();
  Local<Object> self = args.Holder();
  void* ptr = NanGetInternalFieldPointer(self, 0);
  Handle<String> fname = static_cast<CpuProfileNode*>(ptr)->GetFunctionName();
  NanReturnValue(fname);
}

...

Handle<Value> ProfileNode::New(const CpuProfileNode* node) {
  NanScope();

  if (node_template_.IsEmpty()) {
    ProfileNode::Initialize();
  }

  if(!node) {
    return Undefined();
  }
  else {
    Local<Object> obj = NanPersistentToLocal(node_template_)->NewInstance();
    NanSetInternalFieldPointer(obj, 0, const_cast<CpuProfileNode*>(node));
    return obj;
  }
}
```

After refactoring

```
//ProfileNode::Initialize deleted
//ProfileNode::GetFunctionName deleted

Handle<Value> ProfileNode::New(const CpuProfileNode* node) {
  NanScope();

  if(!node) {
    return NanUndefined();
  }
  else {
    //Create new simplest object, instead of new instance of object template
    Local<Object> obj = NanNew<Object>();
    //Append the value to this object
    obj->Set(String::New("functionName"), node->GetFunctionName());
    //Delete internal link.
    //NanSetInternalFieldPointer(obj, 0, const_cast<CpuProfileNode*>(node));
    return obj;
  }
}
```